# What does this symbol represent in circuits?

Tags: electric-circuits, terminology, notation, electronics, electrical-engineering

I was watching a YouTube video on the superposition theorem and came across a symbol :

[image]
The symbol on the right .

He says it's a current source , Is that all it is ? Is there a name to this so that I can further look in to it ?

Sorry if questions like these are not allowed , I'm new to both this site and circuit analysis.

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic In the past, but even now, physicists could teach circuitry and electronics to engineers. On the other hand, the question is quite general, to be of interest for physicists too.

Comment: The symbol on the left is a voltage source (e.g. a battery), the symbol on the right  is an ampere-meter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The name is “current source.” Since you say the video already mentions this, I am not entirely certain what you’re looking for here.

Comment: Maybe he's looking for an explanation what is "a current source" and how it differs from a battery (on the left of the same diagram). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_source

Comment: @NadavHar'El That would be a reasonable question, though to meet the due diligence requirement the OP should explain what about that readily-accessible wiki article is unclear so an answer could be better targeted to their specific misunderstanding.

Comment: @J.Murray I thought it was a fancy device with a fancy name which is a source of current , did not know it was actually called "current source". Much thanks to the both of you .

Answer (score 2):

A current source is a complex (and probably non-existent) power supply with internal resistance which can adjust its terminal voltage (or resistance) so that the current flowing through it is always at a predetermined level.